# Como atribuir um único apelido a 2 colunas de tabelas diferentes?

Tags: mysql

Existe alguma maneira de atribuir um apelido em 2 colunas de tabelas diferentes no `SELECT`?

```
SELECT
(a.coluna1, b.coluna2) as coluna_geral
FROM
tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ...
```

Comment: Não sei para que precisa disso, mas não dá para fazer isso. Era mais fácil se explica-se o que pretende fazer com isso...

Comment: Fazer isso não tem muito sentido... se a retornar um id e b retornar outro id, você vai acabar se perdendo..

Comment: um ALIAS é como um id não pode haver repetido

Comment: No caso tenho um LEFTJOIN abaixo onde existe uma tabela com colunas parecidas, queria centralizar os dados sem precisar fazer no php

Comment: Centralizar como assim?

Comment: Tens de ir buscar uma coluna de cada vez, não tens outra hipótese.

Answer (score 1):

O que está tentando fazer não tem lógica nenhuma na programação. Se você tem dois dados diferentes em duas colunas, dar o mesmo nome pra elas vai fazer com que você perca a referência de uma das duas. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT
  a.coluna, b.coluna
FROM
tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ...

 _________________
| coluna | coluna |
|--------|--------|
| NT     | 554    |
|________|________|
```

O resultado pode ser NT ou 554 e tem 50% de chance de não ser o que você quer.

O que é comum acontecer, é colunas com o mesmo nome ter o mesmo dado, por exemplo:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  compras a
     LEFT JOIN usuarios b ON b.userid = a.userid
[...]

 _________________
| userid | userid |
|--------|--------|
| 12     | 12     |
|________|________|
```

Nesse caso é bom omitir uma das colunas:

```
SELECT
  a.*, b.nome, b.cpf, b.etc
FROM
  compras a
     LEFT JOIN usuarios b ON b.userid = a.userid
[...]
```

Assim já tens o id do usuário na tabela `compras` e o restante dos dados da tabela `usuarios`.

Se você deseja imprimir os dados de duas colunas como se fosse uma, o caminho é concatena-las:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(a.coluna, '-', b.coluna) as coluna
FROM
tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ...

 ________
| coluna |
|--------|
| NT-554 |
|________|
```